# How to show the determinant of $B - I$ is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, braid-groups

Let $n \geq 2$ be a positive integer and

$$\beta_i= \left(
\begin{array}{c|c c|c}
  I_{i-1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  \hline
  0 & 1-q & q & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & I_{n-i-1}
 \end{array}\right)$$

be in $GL_{n}\mathbb{Z}[q^{\pm}]$. If

$$B = \beta_{i_1}\cdots\beta_{i_r}$$

with $i_r \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ for $r\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, I want to show that

$$\det(B-I_{n}) = 0$$

I also should note that $\beta_i$'s match with the unreduced burau representations of $\sigma_i$'s in the braid group $\mathbb{B}_n$.

Comment: The all ones vector is fixed by every $\beta_i$.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: To spell it out a bit more, the equation $\text{det}(B-\lambda I)=0$ is equivalent to the statement that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. In your case $\lambda=1$. To prove $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue, you need only exhibit a vector $v$ such that $Bv=v$. Take $v$ be the all ones vectors, i.e. the vector whose entries are all equal to $1$. Show that $\beta_i(v)=v$ for all $i$.